# Read values for elements of a vector from a df of different length in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes of different lengths, `data` and `freqs`. `freqs` contains word frequencies for nouns listed repeatedly in `data`, so `data` looks like:

```
Session   Noun
1         ball
1         bath
1         bed
2         ball
2         bath
2         bed
...
```

and freqs looks like:

```
Noun    Freq
ball    5177
bath    2176
bed     72681
...
```

I would like to add a new column to `data` with word frequencies for each noun (stored in `freqs`) to every corresponding row in `data`. The result should look like:

```
Session   Noun    Freq
1         ball    5177
1         bath    2176
1         bed     72681
2         ball    5177
2         bath    2176
2         bed     72681
...
```

Is there a way to do this without manually inputting each value?

Comment: Just do a `merge`

Comment: perfect, thank you!